# Storybook default collapse argsTable by category

Tags: javascript, storybook

I am trying to default collapse one of my categories inside of my argsTable since it will contain a lot of controls.

My `argTypes`looks like this

```
{
  "component": {
    "control": "text",
    "table": {
      "category": "Utility"
    }
  },
  "flex": {
    "control": "text",
    "table": {
      "category": "Higher Order Component"
    }
  },
  "display": {
    "control": "text",
    "table": {
      "category": "Higher Order Component"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Is there a option that defaults the table accordion to be closed? And can it be applied per category?